# Permalinks give 404 error in WordPress on AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I have created an AWS (Ubuntu 16.04) AMI. Installed WordPress and uploaded my Custom theme. Both operations went fine.

I put my site inside `/var/www/html`.

This is a fresh installation. I created two two pages `/login` and `/forbidden`. In Permalinks page I have selected **Post Name** option.

The site has `.htaccess` file in place (root) with the following content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But whenever I am trying to access `http://ec2-54-174-120-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com/login` I get 404 error.

Configuration in: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

`DocumentRoot /var/www/html` is set in both `/etc/apache2/sites-availabe/000-default.conf` and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

I restarted Apache server several times with no luck.

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to enable Apache `mod_rewrite` module. You can do it by running the following command:

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`